# Definition of absolutely presentable functor

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a small category and $F \in \widehat{C}$.

"$F$ is absolutely presentable" is defined as "the representable functor $C(F, -):C \rightarrow Sets$ preserves all small colimits".

What is $C(F, -)$ ?

I'm reading this.
(Cauchy completion in category theory
 http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/CTGDC/CTGDC_1986__27_2/CTGDC_1986__27_2_133_0/CTGDC_1986__27_2_133_0.pdf)

The definition is in page 135.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a typo: missing hats.

- Proposition 2. characterizes these '*absolutely representable*' functors (which is not the best choice for name, I think), as exactly the *retracts of representable functors*.
- When the definition is used during Prop.2, it is cited as the cocontinuity of rather
  $$\hat C(F,-):\hat C\to Set$$